# How long should it take to insert a million rows in sql2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'd like to know the theoretical time.  I know that every server will vary some.

I am pulling 1,000,000 99Byte rows from a SQL2K  Database into a SQL2005 DB on the same server instance.

There are indexes on the source table. execution plan indicates `<missing index>`????

There are no indexes on the destination table.

The query is taking about 1 minute.  That seems really really long....considering it's a simple `insert into`

`INSERT INTO EDW.STAGE.DESTINATION
SELECT AccountNumber, CardNumber, FiscalYear, SeqNumber,Category,DateSaved, FullLandValue, FullBuildingValue, TotalValue, ValueExemption,TaxableTotal,DataPreAssesGeneralID,getdate(),2010 FROM SOURCE WHERE FiscalYear = 2010`

### I bet there is a way to speed this up...but how?

## Update

This is actually a dynamic SQL statement. for brevity I only am showing the generated string.  I tested the statement as a dynamic vs t- SQL and the execution times were identical.

Comment: Using Redgates data generator, it took me around a minute and a half to insert 1,000,000 rows.  However, my rows avereaged over 250 bytes.  Indexes on the target table will only slow you down as far as I understand.  Only index that I think could help (and probably not even by that much) here would be on FiscalYear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention indexes on the destination table, but not the source.  If the source table doesn't have a non-clustered index on the FiscalYear column, add one.  That should speed up the inner query (the `SELECT`).

Additionally, you could include the other columns you are selecting on the index to eliminate a key lookup from the execution plan.  (If the columns in the `SELECT` statement represent all the columns in the table, then perhaps a clustered index on the FiscalYear column would be better, but this may interfere with an existing primary key, if there is one.)

Or you could always beef up the hardware on the box, but that might be overkill for optimizing an `INSERT` statement.

Edit:

You could also use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) to move the data.  You can save the SSIS package and either call it from an application or schedule it on the SQL Server.

Comment: I'm viewing this on my IPhone but I think you have it backwards.  My source has indexes.  Destination has no indexes.   My understanding is indexes on the destination actually slow down the insert.  Due to modifying the indexes during each row insert.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain - You're correct in what you say, but I wasn't suggesting to add indexes to your destination table.  You didn't mention in your original post whether your SOURCE table had indexes or not... I was suggesting that if it didn't, adding one on the FiscalYear column might help.  IE it might not be the INSERT that is slowing things down, but rather the inner SELECT.  Honestly, I don't think a minute to run this script for ~1M rows is that bad, but if this index is missing, then it could speed things up.

Comment: You are right I implied in my post the Source had indexes, I simply stated "the destination does not have indexes".  I'll updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

It can take time depending on a lot of things (indexes, indexed views that use the table, foreign keys, hardware, etc...)

You can try to use a bulk insert, which is optimized for this kind of things, but you have to load the data for a file, but that's quite easy, you can even do it from the graphical client

- [SQL official doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [Tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an clustered index on FiscalYear on the source table?
Or an non-clustered covering index?

How long does the SELECT by itself take?

Any triggers on the destination table?

Assuming a linked server is being used, what security is used?

Or is it database to database on the same Instance? If so, were statistics updated on teh source database after it was added to the Instance

Comment: I'll have to test all your questions.  Thanks

Comment: There is a non-clustered index over FiscalYear,Category,DateSaved.  18secs for the select statement.  Not a linked server. Same server instance.  Not sure about the updated statistics

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bulk Insert. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: the statement is dynamic SQL. Not sure that's an option

Comment: THere's an api for the bulk insert, so it's definitely an option.  And even if there weren't you could dynamically generate the command line arguements for the bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependant on the hardware in your server,
disk, cpu and ram speed all matter.

The faster the components the faster the query.